# Building a Tree component using angular js

Tags: angularjs, jstree

I have requirement to build tree exactly like jstree(http://www.jstree.com). Jstree meets all my requirements like adding new node, drag&drop, lazy loading. However my application is built on Angular so wanted to know if building my own Tree component is better vs using a jstree within my own directive. There are pros and cons with both approach.

Pros of Jstree
1) Quick development no need to reinvent the wheel.
2) A thoroughly tested component.
Cons:
1) Dependency on a third party library.
2) Making angular know about jsTree Dom manipulations.

Please let me now what is the best approach.I have also noticed some directives using jstree in github.

Answer (score 2):

Try using angular ui-tree [Angular UI Tree](http://jimliu.github.io/angular-ui-tree/) which is customizable and easy to implement

Comment: I have tried that ,problem with Angular UI tree is it does not say its been tested with Safari.